# Accessing js variable from kotlin

Tags: javascript, kotlin

I have two files: a.js and b.kt.

In a.js I have a variable

`var x = 'something'`

Then I need to access this variable in my kotlin file, like

`var y = x`

`y.doStuff()`

I tried `var y = String.asDynamic().x` and `external` but it didn't work.

So how can I get this variable in kotlin file?

Comment: Check if you are able to get js file in browser ie x

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `window` (the JS global scope object) to a `dynamic` and then access your property on that.

```js
var thing = "hello";
```

```kotlin
fun main() {
    console.log(window.asDynamic().thing.unsafeCast<String>())
}
```

Comment: So i did it and got 

`Module parse failed: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   
| var x = 'something'
> console.log(window.asDynamic().x.unsafeCast<String>())`

Comment: I tested it on my machine, it works perfectly. The error you showed doesn't seem to be related to my answer in any way - it's something to do with your server file path matching